# Is there a SQL select query with following where clause?

Tags: t-sql

Table with Records

```
   ID  Column
    1   Java 8 Update 131 (64-bit)
    2   Java 8 Update 161
    3   Java Auto Updater
    4   Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 102
    5   Java(TM) 6 Update 12
    6   shared.tp.aurora.ooc.java.bundle-4.0-core-nu
    7   olap.oda.api.java-4.0-en-nu
    8   repoaccess.container.java-4.0-core-nu
```

Select Records having "Java Update" only with ID's 1,2,3,4,5

Tried

```
Select ID, Column
where column like '%Java%'

Select ID, Column
where column like '%Java Update%'

Select ID, Column
where column like '%Java*Update%'
```

Comment: `column like '%Java%Update%'`, the `'*'` is not a wildcard.

Comment: `select Id, Column from ElderberrySchnapps where CharIndex( '.', Column ) = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Using an AND:

```
SELECT ID, Column
FROM YourTable
WHERE column like '%Java%' AND column like '%Update%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Column
FROM YourTable
WHERE column like 'Java%Update%'
```

Assuming (not a good thing) you want all rows with Column value that starts with 'Java' and contains 'Update' somewhere after 'Java' - the above will help.